# not able to acces the aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, putty, winscp

I am trying to access aws ec2 instance from putty and winscp but it is not getting connected to the instance. It was getting accessed previously in normal for but dont know from few days it is nt been accesible.
Please can anyone help me with its solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have configured putty and i was successfully accessing the instance using it, but now when I launch my putty instance it stays blank fo a preety long long time

Comment: i think the error is host is not communicating

Comment: And you're communicating with it in exactly the same way under exactly the same conditions? You haven't moved a pem file, say? How about the online java ssh console provided by Amazon? Does that work?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the instance from the AWS Management Console ?

Comment: hey i rebooted the the instance and waited for some time and the instance started working as earlier.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibility that the aws instance may get hanged to the possible solution is to restart the aws instance. But make sure we take the backup of the current instance and restart the hanged instance and after successful restarting deleted the duplicate instance.